# Jsoup.clean() leaves unclosed and opens tags

Tags: java, html, xml, jsoup

The following code replaces this text: `<br />` with `<br>`:

```
String removeDisallowedTags(String textToEscape) {
    Whitelist whitelist = Whitelist.none();
    whitelist.addTags(new String[] { "b", "br", "font" });

    String safe = Jsoup.clean(textToEscape, whitelist);
    return safe;
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Jsoup.clean()` processes the document as HTML by default, and in HTML `<br>` without closing tag is allowed. The same goes with `<img>`.

You have to parse the code as XML. That will leave the tags closed - and it will even close them for you. A fixed method with some additional settings:

```
String cleanXmlAndRemoveUnwantedTags(String textToEscape) {
    Whitelist whitelist = Whitelist.none();
    whitelist.addTags(allowedTags);

    OutputSettings outputSettings = new OutputSettings()
                    .syntax(OutputSettings.Syntax.xml)
                    .charset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                    .prettyPrint(false);

    String safe = Jsoup.clean(textToEscape, "", whitelist, outputSettings);
    return safe;
}
```

Comment: Yes. `<br />` is in fact XHTML and for HTML an unclosed `<br>` is correct.